# MissingTargetException when deploying Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to deploy my cloud function in Python but I'm getting this error below. My function name is `function_1` and only has "main.py" and "requirements.txt" under same basic directory.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_cli())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli
    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 259, in create_app
    raise MissingTargetException(
functions_framework.exceptions.MissingTargetException: File /workspace/main.py is expected to contain a function named function_1
```

Edit: Adding python code below and my entry point name is same as function name if that matters.

```
import requests
import json
from google.cloud import storage

url = "https:/..."
headers = {"Content-Type" : "...",
            "Authorization" : "..."}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

json_data = response.json()
pretty_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket("test_bucket")
blob = bucket.blob("test_blob")

blob.upload_from_string(pretty_json)
```

Please advise!

Comment: Can you paste your function python code?

Comment: Added python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must comply with the product code structure, like this sample in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#sample_usage).

Update your code like that in a file name `main.py`

```
import requests
import json
from google.cloud import storage

def function_1(request):
    url = "https://api.adalo.com/v0/apps/42a58db3-1093-47bf-a95e-9ceb9405b396/collections/t_8cbeae85d781427988deae1c8bf51d72?offset=0&limit=100"
    headers = {"Content-Type" : "application/json",
            "Authorization" : "Bearer 7pd6gjjsytfco4yfn3zxc0f1b"}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    json_data = response.json()
    pretty_json = json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("syr_test_bucket1")
    blob = bucket.blob("test_blob")

    blob.upload_from_string(pretty_json)
```

When you deploy, your function

```
gcloud functions deploy function_1 --runtime=python38 --trigger-http <params...>
```

You need to have the same function (in your code) name as the function (on gcp) name. If not, you can set an entry point

```
gcloud functions deploy function_gcp_name --entry-point=python_function_name --runtime=python38 --trigger-http <params...>
```